# Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n^{13} q^{n}$ where $q \in \mathbb{R}$ converges if and only if $q \in (-1, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If the sum converges, we can argue that if  $q \notin (-1, 1)$ then the necessary condition isn't met which is a contradiction.

For $q=0$ the sum is 0 and if $q \in (0, 1)$ then we can use comparison test. However, I don't know how to approach this for $q \in (-1, 0)$ (or if there's an argument which works for any $q \in (-1, 1)$

Comment: ratio test${}$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng The textbook I'm using for self-study explicitly states that $a_n > 0$ for ratio test but now that I've checked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), it indeed works for all nonzero reals.

In any case, since this series is absolutely convergent for $q \in (0,1)$ then it's convergent for $q \in (-1, 1)$, right?

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^k q^n$ converges for integer k values and $|q|<1$.

Comment: @Ty Yes, but I want to prove this fact ;) Is my logic in the comment above correct? I.e. it's absolutely convergent for $|q| < 1$ therefore it's convergent by the ratio test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to use the comparison test is choose some $q'\in\left(-1,1\right)$ such that $|q'|>|q|$, so:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{13}|q|^n}{{|q|'}^n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^{13}\left|\frac{q}{q'}\right|^n=0
$$
And so for all $n$ bigger than some $N$ we get $0<n^{13}|q|^n<|q'|^n$ so by the comparison test, since the right series converges, so is the left.