# Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n^{13} q^{n}$ where $q \in \mathbb{R}$ converges if and only if $q \in (-1, 1)$ using ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove the statement above and I have found this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711597/prove-sum-infty-n-1-n13-qn-where-q-in-mathbbr-converges-if-a) in which one of the comments suggested to use the ratio test. I have come out with following solution. Is it alright? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$$ $$\dfrac{(n+1)^{13} q  q^{n}}{n^{13}q^n} = \left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)^{13}q = \left(\dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{n}}{1}\right)^{13}q$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left(\dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{n}}{1}\right)^{13}q\right| = \left|q\right| < 1\iff q \in (-1, 1)$$

Comment: The algebra is good, but the inequalities need to be strict (i.e., if the limiting ratio is $1$ the ratio test is inconclusive).

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks!